# 90s book where four characters go to sleep and wake up in a magical medieval world

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm looking for an old book, probably from the 90s or earlier. I think there were four people who played *D&D* in our world, and they went to sleep and woke up in a magical medieval world.

I remember right after they wake up, the "magic user" triggers a fireball spell that ruins some information and stuff that they need, and at least one person gets hurt. I think they are the traditional fighter/barbarian who berserks, magic-user, cleric, and, I think, a thief. There's some bad stuff that happens to them along the way.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Answer (score 4):

[The Sleeping Dragon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/310737.The_Sleeping_Dragon) from 1983, first book of Joel Rosenberg's [Guardians of the Flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame) series?

A group of college students who are playing an AD&D like game with a professor as GM suddenly find themselves in the game world, as their characters. There's a Fighter, a couple of Thieves, a Cleric, Wizards and a dwarf (fighter). Lots of bad stuff, including characters dying, happens during the book and series in general. Early on a wizard accidentally destroys most of their belongings with a spell gone wrong.

I can't remember *how* they transferred to the world, though.

Comment: They do basically fall asleep to the GM's narration of the game (implied to be magic by him). You can check it out at https://archive.org/details/sleepingdragongu0000joel